# Having issue with deleting tableView didselectRowAtIndexPath value from total value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I have two view controllers. The first view controller contains a table view with item names and costs. The second view controller will appear as a pop up screen whenever I click on any table view cell. I can select number of units of that particular selected item like - 1 +

My problem is: when I click on any item in the table view (for example: cost 100 rupees), I am getting the pop up screen and pick a count as 2, so the total cost will be 200 rupees, it is working very fine. Selected item's cost is added to total amount. But the problem is: when I deselect item, added value should be removed from the total value. It is not happening.

The parent view controller:

```
import UIKit
let finalPrice : Int = 0

func expandableTableView(_ expandableTableView: LUExpandableTableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let inPrice = priceArr[indexPath.row]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(inPrice, forKey: "inPrice")

    let cell: UITableViewCell? = expandableTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark

        arrData[indexPath.section].Children?[indexPath.row].isSelected = 1
        let childViewController = childViewControllr(nibName: "childViewController", bundle: nil)

        childViewController.delegate = self
        childViewController.selectsegmentIndex = selectsegmentIndex
        addChildViewController(childViewController)
        view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
        childViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 70, width: self.view.frame.size.width-40, height: self.view.frame.size.height-100)
        childViewController.view.center.x = self.view.center.x
        childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
    else
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
}
func totalCostLbl(data: Int)
{
    print("data \(data)")
    finalPrice = finalPrice + data
    totalPriceLbl.text = "\(finalPrice) Rupees"
}
```

In my child view controller:

```
@IBAction func OkButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    totalPriceCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "inPrice")

    totalPriceCount = totalPriceCount * numOfUnits
    self.delegate?.totalCostLbl(data: totalPriceCount)
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614916-tableview?language=objc

Comment: It's not clear how you are deselecting the item.

Comment: I think by putting just this line **cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none** , you are handling deletion logic.Correct?If yes then that is not correct way.You need to pass reduced price & item count  ** func totalCostLbl(data: Int)**  to this method